# Long http latency on node js server

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, express, apple-push-notifications

Good evening,
We have a nodejs server (running on expressJs) on a dedicated server that we use as a push notification server.We also have an API (PHP) on a server that communicates with  nodeJs server (just Emt signal with a small payload) .Once our API sends a signal to the server nodejs we send notifications to ios device (with node-apns) android (with node-fcm) and web with socket (socket.io).
The problem is that the monitor of our application shows that the http latency can http rises beyond 60000 milisecond and I do not know why, but it has the consequence that the notification is received in very wide delays (more than 1 minute after the emission of signal).Average size of the payload of a notification is 1Kb.

Comment: use rabbitmq, redismq and etc. message queue systems to not to wait for response after http

Comment: it needs debugging, You'll not find quick solution. so add me in skype: anarjafarov and let's talk

Comment: There is a bug with too many connections opened to database. I used connectionPool to fix it

Comment: have You succeeded to fix issue?